# Nodejs Websocket Speed

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am building a multiplayer game and am using websockets as the data transfer for playing. I want to know how many ms it takes for a message to be send from the client to the server and the server to the client. I am using nodejs websocket package ws

Comment: This is like asking how long would it take to drive from your house to my house. You'll notice that neither of us know where the other lives, how far apart we are, if we live across oceans or on top of mountains... and then you'll realise the problem with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know how much MS it takes is not an answer anyone can directly give ... that is entirely dependent on the hardware you are running your source code on as well as the latency of the recipient